# React - How to get the value of the hooks inside the context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components, react-context

I have a **LessonThemes** component. I use a hook then I use the **context** to apply logic inside the **Test** component, the problem is that I don't understand how to get the `color` value from the hook and apply it inside the **context**. `export const CounterContext = createContext ([ ]);` I need to apply value `color` inside `CounterContext`

[image]

**LessonThemes.jsx**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, createContext} from "react";
import ThemeContext from "./ThemeContext";

export default function LessonThemes(props) {
    const [color, setColor] = useState(localStorage.getItem("color"));

    const [themes, setThemes] = useState([
        { name: "G", color: "green" },
        { name: "R", color: "red" },
        { name: "B", color: "blue" },
    ])

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("color", color);
    })

    const SideBarPageContent = (SideBarPageContentBackground) => {
        localStorage.setItem('color', SideBarPageContentBackground);
        setColor(SideBarPageContentBackground);
    }

    return (
        <CounterContext.Provider value={[color, setColor]}>
            {
                themes.map((theme, index) => {
                    return (
                        <label key={index}>
                            <input
                                onChange={() => SideBarPageContent(theme.color)}
                                type="radio"
                                name="background"
                            />{theme.name}</label>
                    );
                })
            }
        </CounterContext.Provider>
    );
}

export const CounterContext = createContext([]);
```

**Lesson.js**

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import "./css/Sidebar.css";

export default function Test(props) {
    const [color] = useContext(CounterContext);

    return (
        <div className="page-wrapper chiller-theme toggled">
            <LessonThemes />
            <div style={{background: color}}>
                <i className="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: you can use `useContext`

Comment: `createContext([]);` creates a context, the parameter passed to it is the default value to be used if no provider sits above a consumer in the React component tree. `<CounterContext.Provider value={[color, setColor]}>` provides a `CounterContext` to any consumer that appears in the component tree below it (the values provided are the same as the values provided to the Provider value prop). When multiple Providers for the same context appear in the component tree the most relevant context is used (closest provider heading up the component tree).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the way you are doing it, but it's not clear on how you need to consume that `Context.Provider`.

I'm assuming you've made an example with minimal functionality, because from your example code, there is no need to the `Context` to be there in the first place, since you are not rendering any component "under" the context provider.

This is how you would consume it from a nested component. I.e: a component under the `<YourContext.Provider/>`.

```js
const CounterContext = React.createContext([]);

function LessonThemes(props) {
  const [color, setColor] = React.useState("initialColor");

  const [themes, setThemes] = React.useState([
    { name: "G", color: "green" },
    { name: "R", color: "red" },
    { name: "B", color: "blue" },
  ])
  
  const inputItems = themes.map((theme,index) => (
    <React.Fragment>
       <label key={index}>
         <input
           onChange={() => setColor(theme.color)}
           type="radio"
           name="background"
         />
         {theme.name}
       </label>
    </React.Fragment>
  ));

  return (
    <CounterContext.Provider value={[color, setColor]}>
      {inputItems}
      <NestedComponent/>
    </CounterContext.Provider>
    );
}

// NESTED COMPONENT THAT WILL CONSUME THE CONTEXT

function NestedComponent() {
  const [color,setColor] = React.useContext(CounterContext);
  return(
    <div>
      <div>I am NestedComponent</div>
      <div><b>color:</b>{color}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<LessonThemes/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: Let me demonstrate my Test component where I am trying to apply the color value inside jsx, I have edited my question you can look at the Test component

Comment: Is that component under any `CounterContext.Provider` ? React will try to find one in the tree above your Test component. Otherwill it will use the initial value from `createContext`.

Comment: This is the problem, the LessonThemes component I am trying to import inside the Test component and not vice versa